# Multi word Search of SQL database, return results in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Hi I've been stuck all night on this, and have turned to my best friends the stack overflow

i am trying to enter more then one word into a text box on one page and then perform some sort of action that allows for the program to split the words into and array and search my database table for all the words entered, i know i should implement an OR statement somewhere but its hard :s any help would be appreciated. This is what i have so far

```
public string[] ResultsQuery;
public int i;
public string criteria;


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ResultsQuery = Request.QueryString["search"].Split(' ');




    foreach (string sWord in ResultsQuery)
    {

        criteria += "ItemName LIKE '%" + ResultsQuery[i] + "%'";

        i++;


    }


    sqlResults.SelectCommand = "SELECT ItemName, Price, Description FROM ITEM WHERE " + criteria;
```

i think I'm on the right track, i just keep getting errors. THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below

```
foreach (string sWord in ResultsQuery))
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria)
         criteria +="  OR ";

    criteria += " ItemName LIKE '%" + sWord  + "%' ";

}
```

- if you have multiple items then you need to add `OR` condition between those
- You need spaces before and after each item otherwise when you spending your final sql will be wrong

EDIT: Just cleaned it up a bit.

Comment: OMG this worked thank you so much please explain what its doing